# $and operator always return true even though i think it should be false

Tags: mongodb

I try to set up reset password feature. User will receive a link in their email containing token to reset their password. the link looks like this :

```
http://localhost:3000/api/users/reset?token=dasdasad&id=5cb99eee1e7de74d69bbf426
```

where token is secret reset token generated by crypto.randombyte and ID is user's obejectID.

Here's step of my reset password function :

1. Validate user's input
2. Check if secret token provided by user is the same as in my database
3. If it is, then update user's password
4. delete reset token stored in my databse

I try to do step 2 - 4 in one query but it doesnt work. Somehow user always able to update their password in database even though the reset token is wrong.

Here is my code

```
        // setup find criteria
        const criteria = {
          $and: [
            {_id: oid},
            {reset_token: query.token}
          ]
        }


        // hashing new password
        bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, (error, salt) => {
          bcrypt.hash(form.newPassword, salt, (error, hash) => {
            form.newPassword = hash;                      


            // update new password into DB and delete reset token
            users.updateOne(criteria, {$set:{password:form.newPassword}, $unset:{reset_token:""}} )
            .then(response => {
                return res.status(201).json(`Your password has been reset successfully!`);
            })
            .catch(error => res.status(500).json('Sorry something is wrong. Please try again later.'));
            });
        })



        .catch(error => {
            res.status(500).json('Sorry something is wrong, please try again later or contact us for further assistance');
        })
```

I expect when user give wrong token user will get an error message and not able update the database.

Thank you. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: FYI, `{_id: oid, reset_token: query.token}` does exactly the same…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`updateOne` does not *fail* if the query matches nothing. Even if it doesn't match any row, the `catch` won't be invoked. That is reserved for truly catastrophic failures (e.g. database connection failed). If you want to know whether a row was updated or not, check the `.modifiedCount` or `.matchedCount` of [`response`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/index.html#db.collection.updateOne) in your `.then`.

Comment: Ahh it's make sense, thank you so much, it solve my question. But in my mongo (v 4.0.8) i cant find .modifiedCount and .matchedCount instead n and nModified, is it the same?

The response is :
```
{
  "n": 1,
  "nModified": 1,
  "opTime": {
    "ts": "6681644467352502273",
    "t": 1
  },
  "electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000001",
  "ok": 1,
  ...
  }
}
```

The weird thing is i can call `.modifiedCount` and `matchedCount` but i can't call `.n` and `.nModified` can you give me a little bit of explanation please. Thank you.